# Updating mongodb using nodejs and angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I would like to update my mongodb using angularjs and nodejs. I would like to update using the id.

I found the following code which updates object with id 1. I would like to pass the id as a parameter and then update the object

```
module.exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
// get a user with ID of 1
User.findById(1, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // change the users location
  user.auto = 'true';

  // save the user
  user.save(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('User successfully updated!');
  });

});
}
```

Can you help

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the id on the request and then just access it

```
module.exports.updateUser = function (req, res) {
var id = req.body.id;
// get a user with ID of id
User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
  if (err) throw err;
 //update the object like you want
//save the object like you were doing
```

Comment: tHANK YOU SO MUCH CAN YOU SHOW ME HOW TO CALL IT IN ANGULAR CONTROLLER

Comment: for that you should just open another question or something because i am not very used to angular and probably would give you a bad anwser :D